# C++ Excel saving workbook

Tags: c++, excel, interfacing

I'm creating an Excel chart using C++. Im having problem with saving workbook with few sheets. Here is my code:

```
try
{

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr XL;
    XL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
    XL->Visible=false;
    Excel::_WorkbookPtr workbook = XL->Workbooks->Add(Excel::xlWorksheet);
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet= XL->ActiveSheet;


    for (i='1';i<='z';i++){


                pSheet = XL->Worksheets->Add();

                char arr[25];


                    sprintf(arr, "Podaci za %c", i);

                pSheet->Name = arr;

                        ...



    }


pSheet = XL->Worksheets->Add();
pSheet->Name = "some page";

pSheet->SaveAs("c:\\test.xls");



workbook->Close();
XL->Quit();


}

catch(_com_error & error)
{
    printf("\n  Greska u komunikaciji s MS Excelom.");
}

CoUninitialize();
```

I have a for loop that creates few sheets. "..." represents the part of code where i fill tables. It all worked great until i tried saving it. Now when it cones to SaveAs() jumps to catch. I also tried using workbook->saveas("table.xls"); but I dont know the right syntax.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the note, i corrected my post.

Comment: Can you save the sheet? I think you have to save the whole workbook?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the file is not opened when you run your app.